# How to change database of yii2 advanced template

Tags: yii2

How can i change the database information of my yii2 advanced template? 
i cant find the database settings.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-index.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In `/common/config/main-local.php` you set your database settings:

```
'components' => [
        'db' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DATABASE_NAME',
            'username' => 'DATABASE_USER',
            'password' => 'DATABASE_PASSWORD',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ],
```

The installation guide for advanced template is here: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/docs/guide/start-installation.md

Comment: yes. i already do this. and the error is that my mysql is not remotable. ahahha thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The advanced template has `environments` that each define the target specific configuration. Basically after cloning the template you need to make sure you setup the files under the `environments`-folder correctly (it comes with `dev` and `prod` predefined configurations - for development and production environments).
In the config subfolders you'll find the `*-local.php` files that indicate configuration specific to that environment.
For the database you have to look in `common/config/main-local.php`.

After you're done with that, just navigate back to the templates' root folder and run `./init`. It will ask you which environment you want and put the files in place. Switching to another environment is just an `./init` call away.

Obviously you're not obligated to keep on using the environments if you don't have use for it, you might as well modify the `/common/config/main.php` file and add the connection info there. But given that the advanced template assumes multiple deployment stages for your application it is a very good setup.